# Bootstrap data-id not passing value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my code I have

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', 'a#coin', function(){
    // get month
    var val = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.post('alert.php', {coin: val}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the data toggle link for the modal

```
<a id="coin" href="#" data-id="BTC" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alertmodal"><i class="fa fa-bell fa-lg" title="Set Alert for BTC" style="color:orangered"></i></a>
```

And in alert.php I simply have

```
$coin = $_POST['coin'];
echo $coin;
```

The modal is popping up fine its just not passing the data-id value
Unsure as to what Im doing wrong

More code added

```
<?php
require('alert.php');
?>
   <html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#liveprices").load("liveprices.php");
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#liveprices").load("liveprices.php");
        }, 5000);
    });
   </script>

  </head><body>
```

The function discussed here is loaded at the end of the document

Comment: I'm not sure if it will make a difference, but jQuery has a built-in function for accessing `data-*` attributes. `$(this).data('id')`

Comment: It is working for me. I am getting coin value in alert.php. Open your console and look for error

Comment: Nope no change :(

Comment: Says bootstrap.min.js requires Jquery
although jquery is loaded right above it

Comment: I don't think there's any issue with the code here. Can you try this for your bootstrap.min.js?
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: its displaying the correct code in the modal when i look at the console however when i look at the page it still doesnt display BTC

See here : https://snag.gy/kT4jIJ.jpg

Comment: Oh I see. It *might* be the timeout. The console gets updated automatically later when the value is received BUT by the time "modal-body" is being rendered, the value is still not available. Can you re-check on that?

Comment: how would i check that ?

Comment: Add a breakpoint at the point where "modal-body" is receiving content and check whether "BTC" is being received or not. Btw I'm sorry for the delay in responses as I'm not receiving any notifications when you comment.

Comment: can you provide code ? sorry im not a javascript guy im a php guy, I re-used this jquery code from another question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160022/discussion-between-chris-yates-and-shashank).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a [discussion over the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160022/discussion-between-chris-yates-and-shashank) regarding the requirements, we came to a conclusion that PHP is not at all required in this case and simple jQuery does the trick:

**Requirements**:

If you look at this [screenshot](https://snag.gy/kT4jIJ.jpg) 
you will see a list of coin names with an alarm icon .. 
When the relevant alarm icon is clicked I want it to pop up a modal and just assign and echo a variable value ( which will be the coin ) BTC etc

Later on a form will be added which ideally will have that data added to a hidden field ready for submission

**Solution (one approach):**

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sm1c3cwf/1/)

Relevant code changes:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.coin', function(){
    var val = $(this).attr('data-id'), modal = $('div#test-modal');
    console.log(val);
    modal.find('.modal-title').html('Get alerts for ' + val);

    modal.find('.modal-body .alert-notification').html('Get alert notifications when ' + val + ' breaks strong support / resistance lines');

    modal.modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Perfect answer to a really over complicated mess ha ha ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Says bootstrap.min.js requires Jquery although jquery is loaded right
>   above it

By default bootstrap uses jQuery slim version. Slim version do not have `$.ajax` and related functions. Use the jQuery full version.

Use this jQuery

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Below is the comment from the slim version with the features removed

```
/*! jQuery v3.2.1 -ajax,-ajax/jsonp,-ajax/load,-ajax/parseXML,-ajax/script,-ajax/var/location,-ajax/var/nonce,-ajax/var/rquery,-ajax/xhr,-manipulation/_evalUrl,-event/ajax,-effects,-effects/Tween,-effects/animatedSelector | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */
```

Comment: Have changed
although as per the answer below Im getting an error in the console
ev is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (index.php:263)

Comment: It could be a different issue, what do you have in line 263? Can you post full code. @ChrisYates

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `document.on('click')`, the `$(this)` may be somewhat confused. I might try `$(event.target).closest('a#coin')` in place of `$(this)` and see if it helps:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#coin', function(event) {
    var val = $(event.target).closest('a#coin');
    console.log(val);
});
```

Comment: getting Uncaught ReferenceError: ev is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (index.php:263)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:4676)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4360)

Comment: I was switching between `ev` and `event` as a variable name. Fixed now. But check the other posted answer, looks like it may speak to your direct console error.

Comment: Ive change jQuery versions and nothing
Im now getting these errors
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at Build.params(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js:8411:4)
    at Function.jQuery.param (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js:8450:4)
    at Function.ajax (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js:9040:20)
    at Function.jQuery.(anonymous function) [as post] (ht

Comment: This really does sound like it's related to the jquery version, or the order your scripts are running in. You may need to post more code showing those details.

Comment: <script async type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script async type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>